# POWER BI calculated column with data from different tables and key value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables:  BUDGET (salesPerson; customer; value) and INVOICES (salesPerson; customer; invoice; value).

Example:

```
BUDGET: 
Anna;  customerA; 100 
Anna;  customerB; 200 
Marco; customerC; 500
Marco; customerD; 100
```

---

```
INVOICES: 

Anna;  customerA; first;  10 
Anna;  customerA; second; 15
Anna;  customerA; third;  10
Anna;  customerB; first;  20 
Anna;  customerB; second; 60
Marco; customerC; first;  50
Marco; customerC; second;
```

the key to link the tables is the salesPerson.

I want to make a table report done in this way: 
salesPerson; total budget; total amount invoiced; % invoiced on the budget

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Rado mentioned, you can use Summrize function to generate the customer and sales person table and then connect them . Then it be a lot easier